# Second degree connection ranking

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x, graph

> **Problem**
>
> Find 2nd degree connections ( friends’ friends), output these 2nd
>   degree connections ranked by number of common friends (i.e 1st degree
>   connections) with you, (example: if 2nd degree connection A has 10
>   common friends (1st degree connections) with you but 2nd degree
>   connection B has 8 common friends (1st degree connections)with you,
>   then A should be ranked first) Input is your connection graph
>   represented by undirected graph nodes, output is list of 2nd degree
>   connections represented by graph nodes.

My current solution is to find all first degree connection, and then for each first degree connection, I try to find true (i.e. not overlapped with first degree connection) second degree connection, and build a common connection (between self, and 2nd degree connection) frequency dictionary. Finally, I sort the dictionary by frequency.

I'm wondering if any advice of more efficient implementation (in terms of algorithm time complexity), bugs in my code and code style advice. I am thinking of using BFS could improve performance (in terms of algorithm time complexity) for this problem.

```
from collections import defaultdict
class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.out_neighbour = defaultdict(list)
    def add_edge(self, from_node, to_node):
        self.out_neighbour[from_node].append(to_node)
        self.out_neighbour[to_node].append(from_node)
    def second_order_rank(self, from_node):
        first_order_set = set()
        for n in self.out_neighbour[from_node]:
            first_order_set.add(n)
        second_order_rank = defaultdict(int) # key: node id, value: count of common first order connection
        for first_order_node in self.out_neighbour[from_node]:
            for second_order_node in self.out_neighbour[first_order_node]:
                if second_order_node == from_node or second_order_node in first_order_set:
                    continue
                for second_order_neighbour in self.out_neighbour[second_order_node]:
                    if second_order_neighbour in first_order_set:
                        second_order_rank[second_order_node] += 1
        rank_order = []
        for n,c in second_order_rank.items():
            rank_order.append((c,n))
        rank_order = sorted(rank_order, reverse=True)
        result = []
        for r in rank_order:
            result.append(r[1])
        return result
if __name__ == "__main__":
    g = Graph()
    edges = [(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(3,4),(3,6),(4,7),(4,10),(5,9),(6,8)]
    for e in edges:
        g.add_edge(e[0],e[1])
    print g.second_order_rank(1)
```

Comment: A person can be both a friend and a feiend's friend, I see no way these conditions are mutually exclusive

Comment: I would only write code to go "one level deeper" and use in a loop to go arbitrarly deep into the network.

Comment: @Caridorc, "see no way these conditions are mutually exclusive" -- for a person to be both friend and friend's friend, do you mean they should be 2nd degree connection, or not?

Comment: @Caridorc, that's great, looking forward to your `one level deeper` solution. :)

Comment: Yes they should be

Comment: I do not know how to write it, , it was just an idea